# Trying to convert external code to a full fledged bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, npm, bookmarklet

I am trying to convert the following Javascript snippet into a regular bookmarklet by geting the code from the link and replacing the link with the direct code:

```js
javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.append(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init(); } })();
```

But, I can't get that to work for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems like a regular bookmarklet to me. What is the exact change you want to do? And what specifically doesn't work? Also, you've tagged this with npm - how is that relevant?

Comment: I want to get the code from the URL inside the bookmarklet. I tagged this with npm because the Code from the URL is .npm code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL gets too long or cannot be parsed

For example Chrome says:

> 413. That’s an error.
>      Your client issued a request that was too large. That’s all we know.

when I do

`javascript: (code from url)()`

Comment: Darn. =| I guess that doesn't work